# Wndow is not being created in Eclipse c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, glfw, glew

I use the Eclipse IDE and the `glfw`, `glew`, and `glm` libraries. I want to create a window, but when I run the code nothing happens. Earlier, when I tried to launch it, it was written in the console "Info: Do not build anything", but now this phrase appears for a moment and disappears. And if I erase the contents of int `main()`, and write for example: `cout << "hello world<<endl;`, then the text will be output to the console, but for some reason, the code for creating the window does not work.

I tried reinstalling Eclipse, but nothing changes. I am new to programming in Eclipse, I had to spend about 10 hours fixing other errors that did not even allow me to run the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

int WIDTH = 1280;
int HEIGHT = 720;

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Window", nullptr, nullptr);
    if(window == nullptr) {
        cerr << "Failed to create GLFW Window" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        cerr << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glViewport(0,0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the problem has nothing to do with eclipse so I don't know why you keep talking about eclipse

Comment: why does it have nothing to do with eclipse if I run the code in it

Comment: which platform, windows/linux/mac ?

Comment: i use windows 10

Comment: @cserax Eclipse is simply a tool for editing compiling and debugging code. The way you edit the code won't have any effect on the built program and Eclipse farms out the building to other tools. There may be problems convincing eclipse to configure the build process correctly, but usually you don't get a runnable program if the configuration is incorrect. When it comes to running the program, Eclipse just supplies a terminal for you and the program to type in. You've proved that this is working.

Comment: To be absolutely certain you can cut Eclipse out of the loop by running the program directly from the the command line. If you get identical behaviour it has nothing to do with Eclipse.

Comment: when I run it in the cmd, errors appear: `undefined reference to '_imp__glfwInit'`